# Can Databricks Dolly be trained on Databricks tables for generating insights using prompts?

Tags: databricks, prompt, delta-lake, large-language-model, databricks-dolly

I'm exploring the capabilities of Databricks specifically `Databricks Dolly`, and I'm wondering if it's possible to train Dolly on Databricks tables to generate insights by writing prompts.

I have a Databricks environment set up and I'm working with `Databricks Delta tables`. I'm not sure if Dolly can be utilized to train on my existing Databricks tables and generate insights through prompts.

I would like to leverage Databricks Dolly's capabilities to derive meaningful insights from my data by writing prompts and having Dolly generate responses based on the training it receives. Is this possible with Databricks Dolly? If so, what steps or considerations should I keep in mind to accomplish this?

I appreciate any insights, guidance, or resources you can provide regarding training Databricks Dolly on Databricks tables and using prompts to obtain insights. Thank you!